# Finding unique values in a column based on a condition in another column using r

Tags: r

Given a conditional value in one column, I'm trying to get the unique list of values in another column using 'r'. For instance, if the input was sex = "M", then the output should be a list of unique names (John, Allan, Matt, Chris). 
if input were Country = US, then return a list of unique names (John, Kate). any solutions would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Country        Name      Sex
US             John       M
US             John       M
US             Kate       F
Canada         Allan      M
Canada         Kate       F
Canada         Matt       M 
England        Nicole     F
Germany        Kate       F
Germany        Matt       M 
Germany        Chris      M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you just need to use [subset](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/subset)

You would use it as

```
subset(data,sex=="m",select=c("whatever","cols you want to keep"))
```

Note if you want all of them, you don't need to put anything for select.

And if you've got duplicates, you can get only the [unique](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html) entries by running unique() on it.

For your data, this would be something like...

```
mydat=read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)
unique(subset(mydat, Sex=="M"))
   Country  Name Sex
1       US  John   M
4   Canada Allan   M
6   Canada  Matt   M
9  Germany  Matt   M
10 Germany Chris   M
```

Comment: thanks Ray. is there as way to get the vector ("john", "Allan", "Matt", "Chris") instead of subsetting the entire dataset?

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this.

    mydat$Name[mydat$Sex=="M"]

is one way.

That will have two Matt's because there is a Canadian Matt and a German Matt. To get only the unique, run unique on the above.